# Does reaction use up an action? Must bonus actions happen after an action?

Tags: dnd-5e

Let's say a character has a spell with a reaction, like Hellish Rebuke.  If they use this in response to taking damage can they still use an action that round?

Related, but not the same, is there an order to an action and a bonus action?  For example, can a Rogue with Cunning Action use their bonus action to move their mage hand and then take an action or must it be in reverse order?

Comment: Please post different related questions separately. We have a one-post, one-question policy in order to ensure that answers are focused fully on one question at a time. (I believe your second question has already been asked & answered, even, and posting it separately allows us to direct you to the canonical Q&A.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No and no

**Reactions** are completely independent from actions, using one does not interfere with the other. (except for readied actions, which uses both)

**Bonus actions** can be used any time in your turn, unless the rule that provides it says otherwise.
For example Flurry of Blows can only be used after the action:

> *Immediately after* you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two unarmed strikes as a bonus action.